# grouping express routes into a single file

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I trying to express routes into a single file using app.use

**app.js**

```js
import express from 'express'
import testRouter from 'testRouter'

const app = express()

app.use('/testRouter', testRouter)

app.listen(3000)
```

**testRouter.js**

```js
import express from 'express'
const router = express.Router
router.get("/page1", function (req, res){
   res.send("test")
})

export default router
```

using module exports is a official ways to do it and it worked

But why doesn't the router definition inside a function work like bellow?

app.js

```js
import express from 'express'
import testRouter from 'testRouter'

const app = express()

app.use('/testRouter', function (){
   const router = express.Router()
   router.get("/page1", function (req, res){
       res.send("test")
   })
   return router
}))

app.listen(3000)
```

Comment: In the correct code, the second argument to the `app.use()` call is the router object. In the bad code, the second argument is a function that doesn't run until a user visits `localhost:3000/testRouter`. To do the same thing in a single file you need to actually write code that does the same thing. You can simply do `app.get("/testRouter/page1", ...);` instead.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe the code inside `app.use('/test/Router', function() { })` executes until a user has visited your test/Router page at least once. I'm also not sure if you can use a middleware ("use") without having an eventual terminal endpoint.

Answer (score 0):

Because in the official documentation **testRouter** is an **Object**

```
app.use('/testRouter', Object)
```

You put the function

```
app.use('/testRouter', Functon)
```

Comment: I solved it by rewriting the function as an Immediately-invoked Function. Thank you for taking the time